# Cannot read from stdin extended ASCII character in NCURSES

Tags: c, ncurses

I have a problem trying to read extended ASCII chars in NCURSES.

I have this program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main () {
    initscr();
    int d = getch();
    mvprintw(0, 0, "letter: %c.", d);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I build it with: gcc -lncursesw a.c

If I type a character in the 7bit ascii, like the 'e' char, I get:

```
letter: e.
```

And then I have to type another for the program to end.

If I type a character in the extended ascii, like the 'á' char, I get:

```
letter:  .
```

and the program ends.

Its like the second byte is read as another character.

How can I get the correct char 'á' ???

Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard "Extended ASCII". Just a bunch of various encodings. It is not clear which one your terminal uses, possibly UTF-8 which is a varable-length code. Thus, you have to read multiple `char`s to compose a character. You should verify and check if ncurses provides functions to handle this, e.g. using wide `char`s.

Comment: I don't know about ncurses, but the Windows `conio.h` function `getch()` returns 2 values on successive calls when some keys, like the function keys are pressed. Write a simple program to display the (numeric) result of successive key presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters that you want to type require the program to setup the *locale*.  As described in the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization):

```
Initialization

   The  library uses the locale which the calling program has
   initialized.  That is normally done with setlocale:

         setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

   If the locale is not initialized, the library assumes that
   characters  are  printable  as in ISO-8859-1, to work with
   certain legacy programs.  You should initialize the locale
   and  not  rely on specific details of the library when the
   locale has not been setup.
```

Past that, it is likely that your locale uses UTF-8.  To work with UTF-8, you should compile and link against the *ncursesw* library.

Further, the `getch` function only returns values for single-byte encodings, such as ISO-8859-1, which some people confuse with [Windows cp1252](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html), and thence to "Extended ASCII" (which says something about two fallacies not cancelling out).  UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding.  If you use `getch` to read *that*, you will get the first byte of the character.

Instead, to read *UTF-8*, you should use [`get_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html) (unless you want to decode the UTF-8 yourself).  Here is a revised program which does that:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int
main(void)
{   
    wint_t value;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    get_wch(&value);
    mvprintw(0, 0, "letter: %#x.", value);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I printed the result as a number, because [`printw`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_printw.3x.html) does not know about Unicode values.  `printw` uses the same C runtime support as `printf`, so you may be able to print the value directly.  For instance, I see that [POSIX `printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) has a formatting option for handling `wint_t`:

> **`c`**
>   The `int` argument shall be converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting byte shall be written.
>   
>   If an **`l`** (*ell*) qualifier is present, the `wint_t` argument shall be converted as if by an **`ls`** conversion specification with no precision and an argument that points to a two-element array of type `wchar_t`, the first element of which contains the `wint_t` argument to the **`ls`** conversion specification and the second element contains a null wide character.

Since ncurses works on many platforms, not all of those actually *support* the feature.  But you can probably assume it works with the GNU C library: most distributions routinely provide workable locale configurations.

Doing that, the example is more interesting:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int
main(void)
{   
    wint_t value;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    get_wch(&value);
    mvprintw(0, 0, "letter: %#x (%lc).", value, value);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am linking against ncursesw..I did add setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); before initscr(), but now I get..                      " etter:  M-!", without the quotes..

Comment: I made it work in another computer just like you showed it!! Does exist a "mvwprintw" like function but for Wide Chars???